# Calculate maximum stack size for tree traversal

Tags: algorithm, tree, tree-traversal, space-complexity

I implemented a tree traversal algorithm for n-ary trees which follows pre-order and uses a stack instead of recursion. In pseudo code, the algorithm looks like this:

- Create an empty stack `stack` and push root node to stack.
- Do following while `stack` is not empty.

  - Pop an item from `stack` and print it. Optional: if artifical end node, continue
  - Optional: Push a artifical node `node_end` to `stack`
  - Push all children from right to left to `stack`

The optional part is for a use case where I print an XML document which is kept as a tree structure. Visiting a node `X` prints the start tag, visiting the artifical node `X_end` prints the corresponding end tag.

Drawing here is quite rough so I give the tree in C++ code.

```
struct Node {
    int id; // root is 0
    std::vector<int> children; // index in the vector
}

std::array<Node, 15> tree{};

// sets all the ids, in total we have 15 nodes
for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
    tree[i].id = i;

// now all the children, hope one can see the tree structure
tree[0].children.push_back(1);
tree[0].children.push_back(6);
tree[1].children.push_back(2);
tree[1].children.push_back(3);
// 2 is a leaf
tree[3].children.push_back(4);
tree[3].children.push_back(5);
// 4 is a leaf
// 5 is a leaf
tree[6].children.push_back(7);
tree[6].children.push_back(9);
tree[6].children.push_back(12);
tree[7].children.push_back(8);
// 8 is a leaf
tree[9].children.push_back(10);
tree[9].children.push_back(11);
// 10 is a leaf
// 11 is a leaf
tree[12].children.push_back(13);
tree[12].children.push_back(13);
// 13 is a leaf
// 14 is a leaf
```

Now, running the algorithm described above gives the following stacks (one with the artifical end nodes and one without):

```
current_node | stack (simple version)
---------------------------------
      -      | 0
      0      | 6,1
      1      | 6,3,2
      2      | 6,3
      3      | 6,5,4
      4      | 6,5
      5      | 6
      6      | 12,9,7
      7      | 12,9,8
      8      | 12,9
      9      | 12,11,10
      10     | 12,11
      11     | 12
      12     | 14,13
      13     | 14
      14     | -
```

And the second:

```
current_node | stack (with end nodes)
---------------------------------
      -      | 0
      0      | 0e,6,1
      1      | 0e,6,1e,3,2
      2      | 0e,6,1e,3,2e
      2      | 0e,6,1e,3
      3      | 0e,6,1e,3e,5,4
      4      | 0e,6,1e,3e,5,4e
      4      | 0e,6,1e,3e,5
      5      | 0e,6,1e,3e,5e
      5      | 0e,6,1e,3e
      3      | 0e,6,1e
      1      | 0e,6
      6      | 0e,6e,12,9,7
      7      | 0e,6e,12,9,7e,8
      8      | 0e,6e,12,9,7e,8e
      8      | 0e,6e,12,9,7e
      7      | 0e,6e,12,9
      9      | 0e,6e,12,9e,11,10
      10     | 0e,6e,12,9e,11,10e
      10     | 0e,6e,12,9e,11
      11     | 0e,6e,12,9e,11e
      11     | 0e,6e,12,9e
      9      | 0e,6e,12
      12     | 0e,6e,12e,14,13
      13     | 0e,6e,12e,14,13e
      13     | 0e,6e,12e,14
      14     | 0e,6e,12e,14e
      14     | 0e,6e,12e
      12     | 0e,6e
      6      | 0e
      0      | -
```

I really hope I haven't made a typo. If something looks wrong please let me know.

Now to my question: For optimization purposes, it would be nice to know the maximum size of the stack beforehand. I found the following formulas to calculate the required size for a single node.

Simple version:

```
int getRequiredStackSize(Node node)
{
    int sum = 0;
    sum += node.children.size();
    sum += getNumOfRightSiblings(node);
    for (Node parent = getParent(Node); parent != NULL; parent = getParent(parent))
        sum += getNumOfRightSiblings(parent);
    return sum;
}
```

The overall maximum stack size is the maximum for all nodes. Maybe this can be done with fewer calculations?

And for the second case:

```
int getRequiredStackSize(Node node)
{
    int sum = 1; // the node's own artifical end node
    sum += node.children.size();
    sum += getNumOfRightSiblings(node);
    for (Node parent = getParent(Node); parent != NULL; parent = getParent(parent))
        sum += (1 + getNumOfRightSiblings(parent)); // the parents artifical end node as well
    return sum;
}
```

Here I think it is possible to only calculate the values for the leftmost leaves in each group of siblings (how do you call a group of leaves under the same parent?) and take the maximum of those.

First question: Can these formulas be somehow optimized?

Second question: How do I efficiently calculate the maximum? Note: I do construct the tree myself, so I could keep counters etc.

Comment: Why push all the children ?  Why not push the parent + 'index' of next child to process ?  Then stack is bounded by the maximum depth of children with children... though to find that you still need to walk the tree... but you may be able to set a "reasonable" maximum depth if you don't have to multiply up by the number of children in a node ?

Comment: @ChrisHall The maximum depth of children with children? So in simple terms the height of the tree? If you'd give me a short description of the algorithm? In any case, this adds a few extra comparions (`if (childIndex < children.size())`) for some nodes and I prefer speed over required memory. The reason I ask is not that I want to keep the stack small, but to b able to preallocate it (preferrably with the exact required size).

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to optimize here? Are you trying to avoid resizing the stack as more nodes are added? That's probably a case of premature optimization. My suggestion is that you do some performance testing. One case is letting the stack resize automatically as needed. The second, allocate the stack to be the full size of the tree. How much faster (if any) is the second case? Is the difference more than whatever time it would take to compute the maximum depth of the tree?

Comment: @JimMischel Even so, it's still an interesting question I'm wrapping my head around. I'll traverse the tree multiple times, so allocations might matter. But yes, you are totally right, no change can be called an optimization if no measurement was done.

Comment: If you think it's a problem for subsequent traversals, then let the stack automatically size the first time through, and keep track of the maximum. On subsequent traversals, make that value the initial allocation. What you're trying to do doesn't make much sense to me because you have to traverse the tree to find the depth, so you can optimize traversing the tree.

Comment: That is part of the question: Do I really have to traverse the tree? I can keep track of its height and other properties while I construct it. Just asking if there is a more clever way than the formulas I have. I get your point, there are many (and probably equally good) ways to achieve the same goal. But I still think it's an interesting question to solve.

Comment: You can easily keep track of the maximum depth while you're constructing the tree. You know the depth of a leaf when you add it, so it's a trivial matter to check that against the current maximum depth. Maintaining the depth if you delete nodes or do anything but add more nodes is more difficult.